BLS/tz4 signature with Tezos ecosystem
Related to this question I asked few days ago - is there any way of signing text message or byte sequence with BLS key, in Tezos ecosystem? octez suite or any wallet? I tried octez, first I created keypair with:
octez-client -E http://localhost:8732 gen keys bls1 -s bls

Then I tried signing byte sequence with that key:
octez-client -E http://localhost:8732 sign bytes 0x03 for bls1

I got:
Found an aggregate secret key where a non-aggregate one was expected.


I could not reproduce your error, the second command gave me Signature: BLsigBfUJ8xXr9RRp1YhUiPYxwCUjuXHnrThgCZY3YVBwC3ikLysxkQvLhoEChM5AoETmU1cq4FDzVpQfHnVvDyLaMErzfEJ6uf5mmy7ya6MDkCBkiJvQ4M7yugvLfCi7uZm9sfryJAjDY.

@RaphaëlCauderlier Interesting. Which octez version do you use?

@RaphaëlCauderlier maybe you are using testnet? I see that the code which complains about aggregate SK is related to unencrypting SK. Maybe if it is not encrypted, there will be no error, like in your case.

Yes, against testnet it works:
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/sh tezos/tezos:octez-v20.1
octez-client -E https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.com gen keys bls1 -s bls
octez-client -E https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.com sign bytes 0x03 for bls1


@RaphaëlCauderlier Interesting. Which octez version do you use?

40fb8d06 (2024-07-16 13:54:24 +0200) (Octez 20.2)



maybe you are using testnet?

I'm not, actually you don't even need a node for these commands, it's only used for getting the protocol version:
$ ./octez-client --protocol PsParisC sign bytes 0x03 for bls1 works for me.

Thanks to @RaphaëlCauderlier, I found the solution. Error I was referring to appears only if BLS key is encrypted, and key is encrypted by default if you use mainnet RPC. If you use testnet RPC or --protocol PsParisC switch, it would create unencrypted key, you still can create encrypted one with --encrypted switch.

Apparently you spotted a bug, Sylvain R. wrote a fix here: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/14416.
